# Proving the arc length of a certain function is $\infty$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having trouble with a homework problem. We're supposed to prove the following curve has arc length $\infty$ on the interval $[0,1]$:

\begin{gather*} 
f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}: t \to 
\begin{cases}
(0,0) & \text{when t= 0}\\
(t, t\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

I was told by the lecturer that we are obliged to do this using the following formula:

\begin{gather*} 
L(f|_{[0,1]})= \sup\limits_{\mathcal{N} net}L(f|_{[0,1]}, \mathcal{N}) 
\end{gather*}

The net I came up with is $t_{j} = \frac{2}{3+2j}$. This seems right to me intuitively, but I can't seem to find a lower limit for it. I'd greatly appreciate some help with that.

Comment: The integral is not divergent.
$$s(1)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{\mathrm{D}_t[t]^2+\mathrm{D}_t[t\sin(t)]^2}~\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+(\sin(t)+t\cos(t))^2}~\mathrm{d}t\approx1.35134$$

Comment: You can't use that theorem since this isn't a continuous (nor regular) curve, right?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mathcal{N} net$ in $\sup\limits_{\mathcal{N} net}L(f|_{[0,1]}, \mathcal{N})$?

Comment: Presumably, you miscopied. You should have $\sin(1/t)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost supremum over all nets

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right, I'll correct it

Comment: I still don't get why @K.defaoite uses this theorem, since we only proved it in the case when the function is continuous

Comment: @othi The function $f$ is continuous, but the OP changed the definition so that K.defaoite's computation no longer fits.

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm the OP, I'm so terribly sorry, now I see his computation makes sense with my original question. Apologies. Could you take a look at the modified (correct) version please?

Comment: You have give more details. Is a net a partition of $[0,1]$? Do you consider Riemann sums?

Comment: Yeah a net is a partition. For every partition you consider the sum of distances between the images of the elements of the partitions under this function. Take the supremum over all nets.

Comment: Yes, OP indeed changed the post. It was originally $t\sin(t)$.

Comment: Okay, then it just the definition of length for rectifiable curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_n = \frac{2}{2n+1} > 0 $. This sequence is strictly decreasing and $t_1 = \frac{2}{3} < 1$. We have
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{t_n}) = \sin(n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2})  = (-1)^n = \begin{cases} 1 & n \text{ even} \\ -1  & n \text{ odd}  \end{cases},$$
$$t_n  + t_{n+1} = \frac{2}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2n+3} > \frac{1}{n} .$$

For each $k \in \mathbb N$ let
$$\mathcal N_k = \{s_0 = 0,s_1 = t_k, s_2 = t_{k-1}, \ldots, s_k = t_1, s_{k+1} = 1\}. $$
Then
$$L(f|_{[0,1]}, \mathcal{N}_k) =  \sum_{j=0}^k \lVert f((s_{j+1}) - f(s_j)) \rVert > \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \lVert f((s_{j+1}) - f(s_j)) \rVert = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \lVert f(t_i) - f(t_{i+1}) \rVert .$$
For $i = 1,\ldots,k-1$ we have
$$f(t_i) - f(t_{i+1}) = (t_i,t_i\sin(\frac{\pi}{t_i})) - (t_{i+1},t_{i+1}\sin(\frac{\pi}{t_{i+1}})) = (t_i,t_i(-1)^i) - (t_{i+1},t_{i+1}(-1)^{{i+1}})) = (t_i -t_{i+1},(-1)^i(t_i + t_{i+1})) ,$$
thus
$$\lVert f(t_i) - f(t_{i+1}) \rVert = \sqrt{(t_i -t_{i+1})^2 + ((-1)^i(t_i + t_{i+1}))^2} = \sqrt{(t_i -t_{i+1})^2 + (t_i + t_{i+1})^2} >  \sqrt{(t_i + t_{i+1})^2}  = t_i + t_{i+1} > \frac{1}{i} .$$
Therefore
$$L(f|_{[0,1]}, \mathcal{N}_k) > \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{i} .$$
But it is well-known that $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{i} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ (harmonic series).

Comment: Could you clarify why $$t_n  + t_{n+1} = \frac{2}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2n+3} > \frac{1}{n} .$$ is true?

Comment: $t_n  + t_{n+1} = \frac{2}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2n+3}$ is just inserting. The inequality $\frac{2}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2n+3} > \frac{1}{n}$ can be easily verified, simply use the common denominator $n(2n+1)(2n+3)$. The numerator on the LHS is then $8n^2 +8n$, on the RHS $4n^2 + 8n +3$.